# [FLUTTER]: How can I enable/disable the errorText property in InputDecoration in TextField?

Tags: flutter, validation, input, textfield, flutter-web

I need to activate an error message when the input of the form does not respect the allowed characters.
How can I do that?

I tried *errortext*, but if it is active, the error remains even when the input is right.
I need the error message to appear only when the form is **empty** and when the characters entered **do not match** the format.

```
    child: TextField(
                                    controller: state.registrySizeTxtEditCtrl,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      errorText: errText,
                                      enabled: state.revocation,
                                      labelText: 'Registry Size',
                                      hintText: '0 - 1000',
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
                                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                          RegExp(r'^([0-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)$')),
                                    ],),
```

Comment: You can do this in several ways. As an example, you are using errorText so make it `null` when your input is correct. Another way is remove errorText use the `validator`